# Display categories in query results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, echo

I have joined multiple tables with INNER JOIN and got the output which resembles this:

```
SPORT COUNTRY LEAGUE MATCH
SPORT COUNTRY LEAGUE MATCH
SPORT COUNTRY LEAGUE MATCH
```

I'd like SPORT to be displayed only the first time it's found in the query. Same with COUNTRY and LEAGUE, so they serve as a header for the matches. Like this:

```
SPORT
COUNTRY
LEAGUE1
MATCH
MATCH
MATCH
LEAGUE2
MATCH
MATCH
MATCH
```

The code:

```
if ($db_found) {

$SQL ="
select sportname, 
  tournament_templatename, 
  tournament_stagename,    
  GROUP_CONCAT(eventname) as event_name
from ('SELECT 
         event.id AS eventid,
         event.name AS eventname,
         event.tournament_stageFK AS eventtournamentstageFK,
         event.startdate AS eventstartdate,
         tournament_stage.id AS tournament_stageid,
         tournament_stage.name AS tournament_stagename,
         tournament_stage.tournamentFK AS tournament_stagetournamentFK,
         tournament.id AS tournamentid,
         tournament.name AS tournamentname,
         tournament.tournament_templateFK AS tournamenttournament_templateFK,
         tournament_template.id AS tournamenttemplateid,
         tournament_template.name AS tournament_templatename,
         tournament_template.sportFK AS tournament_templatesportFK,
         sport.id AS sportid,
         sport.name AS sportname
       FROM event 
         INNER JOIN tournament_stage 
           ON event.tournament_stageFK=tournament_stage.id
         INNER JOIN tournament 
           ON tournament_stage.tournamentFK=tournament.id 
         INNER JOIN tournament_template 
           ON tournament.tournament_templateFK=tournament_template.id 
         INNER JOIN sport 
           ON tournament_template.sportFK=sport.id
       WHERE
         DATE(event.startdate) = CURRENT_DATE() 
       ORDER BY
         sport.id ASC, tournament_template.name ASC, event.startdate ASC'
     )
GROUP BY 
  sportname, tournament_templatename, tournament_stagename
ORDER BY 
  sportname, tournament_templatename, tournament_stagename";
$result = mysql_query($SQL);

echo "<table border='1' style='border-collapse: collapse;border-color: white;
font-size:8px; background-color: #c8ccce; width:100%;'>";

while($db_field=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
echo  "<tr>" , "<td>" , $db_field['sportname'] , "</td> " , "<td>" ,
$db_field['tournament_templatename'] , "</td>" , "<td>" , 
$db_field['tournament_stagename'] , "</td>" , "<td>" , $db_field['eventstartdate'] ,
"</td>" , "<td>" , $db_field['eventname'] , "</td>" , "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysql_close($db_handle);
}
```

Thanks for helping out a PHP newbie.

Comment: please update your input table with league1, league2. And specify RDMS: (MySQL, Oracle, etc). And your query that produce that result.

Comment: I don't know those 4 columns(sport, country, league, match) to which columns from your query corresponds.

Comment: sport is sport.name, country is tournament_template.name, league is tournament_stage.name, match is event.name. Is that what you asked?

Comment: yes, I updated my answer. it does almost what you want...

Comment: I still don't get it. Can you embed your code in mine?

Comment: your SQL is embeded in mine :) read it again. Will result a big query with your current query in my FROM clause.

Comment: So, in the part from (your old query here) I'm supposed to replace "your old query here" with my $SQL=..."; code or my SELECT... code? I'm really sorry for troubling you this much but I'm not sure what to do and I think your solution might work.

Comment: only the "SELECT..." code. "$SQL= ..."  is php. If I put it in the answer, it will become too big.

Comment: Like this? from ('SELECT event.id AS eventid, ...

Comment: yes. put your select in mine, where I indicated.

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/oddsnavi/public_html/match3.php on line 47 - that's the error for this line: while($db_field=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ ...I have edited the above code to include your code. And the above code is the one giving this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over your query you can:

```
$SQL ="
select sportname, 
   tournament_templatename, 
   tournament_stagename,    
   GROUP_CONCAT(eventname) as eventname
from (
SELECT event.id AS eventid,
event.name AS eventname,
event.tournament_stageFK AS eventtournamentstageFK,
event.startdate AS eventstartdate,
tournament_stage.id AS tournament_stageid,
tournament_stage.name AS tournament_stagename,
tournament_stage.tournamentFK AS tournament_stagetournamentFK,
tournament.id AS tournamentid,
tournament.name AS tournamentname,
tournament.tournament_templateFK AS tournamenttournament_templateFK,
tournament_template.id AS tournamenttemplateid,
tournament_template.name AS tournament_templatename,
tournament_template.sportFK AS tournament_templatesportFK,
sport.id AS sportid,
sport.name AS sportname
FROM
event INNER JOIN tournament_stage ON event.tournament_stageFK=tournament_stage.id
INNER JOIN tournament ON tournament_stage.tournamentFK=tournament.id 
INNER JOIN tournament_template 
ON tournament.tournament_templateFK=tournament_template.id 
INNER JOIN sport ON tournament_template.sportFK=sport.id
WHERE
DATE(event.startdate) = CURRENT_DATE() 
) a
group by sportname, tournament_templatename, tournament_stagename
order by sportname, tournament_templatename, tournament_stagename";
```

and then fetch the results, with first 3 columns already unique.

php code remains the same:

```
$result = mysql_query($SQL);

while($db_field=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
echo $db_field['sportname'] , " " , $db_field['tournament_templatename'] , " " ,      
$db_field['tournament_stagename']  ,  " " , $db_field['eventname'];
echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: I've spotted a small typo in my query. Can you run again?

Comment: Unfortunately it's still giving the same error, Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/oddsnavi/public_html/match3.php on line 49 - for line while($db_field=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

Comment: if($result === FALSE) {
    die(mysql_error());
} - when I added this in the code the error message is "Every derived table must have its own alias"

Comment: wow, that's a simple MySql specific error. I've added the alias.

Comment: Works now! What was the problem?

Comment: inner query (your query) needed an alias.It is an 'a' :)

Comment: Thanks mate. It's still not producing the output I want because the events (matches) are listed one behind the other and not one below the other but I'll work on it. As soon as I reach reputation 75 I'll give you some bounty for this, it's the least I can do. I'm sorry for all this trouble and thanks again!

Comment: for better alignment of matches you can use `GROUP_CONCAT(eventname SEPARATOR ' ' )` or  `GROUP_CONCAT(eventname SEPARATOR '\n' )` or `GROUP_CONCAT(eventname SEPARATOR '\r\n' )` and if you like my solution, you can upvote it, don't spend your reputation points.

Comment: another ideea `GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(eventname,'<br>') SEPARATOR ' ')` :)

Answer (score 0):

SQL does not support that type of breakout. You have to parse through all the data and perfom your own header/detail breakout.

Answer (score 0):

Then you should count results. Just count every time you display your output, and if result want do it more then 1 time, just return null.